# How to "HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(col1, col2))"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

So I have a table with three columns - `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. I need to select those values of `col1` that share rows with *only* one combinarion of `col2` and `col3`. In ideal world I would write this:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(col2, col3)) = 1
```

How to do that in the real world?

So far I have two solutions - group by `col1` and `col2` and by `col1` and `col3` them join results; or group by all three then group that by `col1`. Unfortunately I get (very) different wor counts.

The database is on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Do you want to match where there is only one col2 or col3 value, do you care if there is one of each/multiple but on different rows?  If you give some sample data and what you'd want back it'd be easier to help

Comment: col1 never equals col2 or col3. Imagine if table tracks dinners at the restorant: col1 is a name, col2 is restorant and col3 is day of weak. I'm only interested in people that eat-out in only one restorant and alway on the same day ow weak.

Comment: Well that's why I've voted to withdraw my own answer - your question was unclear and my response won't work.  However if one person eats out at a different restaurant each night, how many times should they be returned in the result set?

Comment: @KAJ - Zero. Clearly they don't meet the criteria stated `I'm only interested in people that eat-out in only one restorant and alway on the same day ow weak.` Not sure what is unclear?

Comment: If that is the case, then the question has been answered.

Comment: @Martin Smith: my point was directed to those who had provided answers to that point - in the form at the time they would return col1 for every unique combination of col2&col3. After edits they do give the sole combination required

Comment: @KAJ - None of the answers have been edited as you suggest as far as I'm aware. Certainly mine wasn't and pretty sure gbn's one wasn't either (the only change I saw was adding a second method)

Comment: @Martin Smith: I added an answer; I deleted it once it became clear that it wasn't what was required. So you can no longer see it.

Comment: @KAJ - So it seems you were in fact the only person who found it unclear then and everyone else understood it fine. I don't think it is fair to blame the question then. BTW 10K+ users can see deleted answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
HAVING MAX(col2) = MIN(col2) AND MAX(col3) = MIN(col3)
```

More complex:

```
SELECT col1
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        col1, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2, col3) as rn
    FROM table
    ) T
GROUP BY col1
HAVING MAX(rn) = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from mycols
where col1 in (
    select max(col1)
    from mycols 
    group by col2, col3
    having count(col1)=1
)
```